# Is there a system call in linux to reserve virtual address space (not memory, just address space)

Tags: c, linux, process, mmap, virtual-address-space

I have a user space "platform" forking different processes. All these processes start executing a platform `plat_init()` function, and then run some other application code (which is not mine. i.e. I cannot change this code).
At some point in time some of these processes may do a `plat_shared_mem_alloc()` to allocate shared memory. This function returns a handle H (one handle per shared memory block allocated at each call). Another function, `plat_get_shared_memory_address(H)` can be called to retrieve the address (in the process virtual space) of H.
H can be sent to other linux processes (using usual IPC).
I would like any call to `plat_get_shared_memory_address(H)` made by any processes to return the same address (for the same handle H).

In other words, I want to map the shared physical memory to the same virtual address in all processes using it, regardless on when the mapping is done.

I thought the `plat_shared_mem_alloc()` could call `shm_open(`) to create a "file" in the file system, and I am aware `mmap()` has the `MAP_FIXED` flag to force the virtual address of the mapping.

But nothing guarantee that if a process P1 maps a shared memory handle at address *A*, then the same address *A* is/will be available in another process P2 address space. Maybe P2's application's code has already mapped something at address *A* before calling `plat_get_shared_memory_address(H)`, and `mmap()` will fail.

So I am thinking of blocking some address space in each process during plat_init() call (which I know comes first). and using some of that address space when needed for `mmap()`.

In other words, is there a system call to block (reserve) some virtual address space of a process (without allocation any memory at this time), so I could, later on, if needed, map things at the same address in my different processes?

Comment: *Maybe P2's application's code has already mapped something at address A before calling `plat_get_shared_memory_address(H)`, and `mmap()` will fail.*  It's more likely that `mmap()` will succeed and cause what was originally at that address to be `munmap()`'d and replaced with the new mapping.

Comment: ho? would it do so? strange behavior. But anyway, that is not what I want either!

Comment: I am now using mmap(... PROT_NONE ...) hoping it just does what I wish. not sure...